# How can a view detect when it's being attached to its parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a View that needs to detect when it's being attached to its parent view.

In a `ViewGroup` I have the `OnHierarchyChangeListener` which allows me to know when a child view is being added / removed, but I need the opposite thing.

Comment: I thought it was just [onAttachedToWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow())

Comment: I read about the function, but it doesn't seem exactly like what I need. From what I understand, it's called only when the view is about to draw itself, but I have to know when it's added to a parent, which can occur much before the drawing process even starts. Also, I'm not sure about this function's behavior if the view is removed and added to another parent. Does it get called again?

Comment: onDetach will be called, then onAttach, how about overriding them and adding logging yourself to find out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification on View added to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269782/notification-on-view-added-to-parent)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create custom view and do your stuff in its onAttachedToWindow

```
public class CustomView extends View {

   public CustomView(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
       super.onAttachedToWindow();
       Log.d("CustomView", "onAttachedToWindow called for " + getId());
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "added", 1000).show();
   }
}
```

[EDIT 1]

you can ensure that your customview added to correct viewgroup which you want

```
@Override
 protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if(((View)getParent()).getId()== R.id.relativelayout2)
    {           
        Log.d("CustomView","onAttachedToWindow called for " + getId());
        Toast.makeText(context, "added", 1000).show();          
    }

}
```

Comment: But a view is not added to a parent view when it's constructed! I want to know when addView is called on some view group with this view being passed as an argument.

Comment: Please see my comment above. I'm not sure onAttachedToWindow is the right solution for my issue.

Comment: For your issue you should control parent also , you can look at the edited answer

Answer (score 3):

**Solution without having to create a custom view**

If the View is one you can't or don't want to modify, you can use [View.addOnAttachStateChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#addOnAttachStateChangeListener(android.view.View.OnAttachStateChangeListener)) to get hooks when the view is attached to the view hierarchy and when it is detached from the view hierarchy.

Something like:

**Kotlin**

```
view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
  override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View) {
    // Do stuff when view has been attached to window
  }

  override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View) {
    // Do stuff when view has been detached from window
  }
})
```

**Java**

```
view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
    // Do stuff when view has been attached to window
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
    // Do stuff when view has been detached from window
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **kotlin** you can use `doOnAttach` extension function on `View`.

```kotlin
    view.doOnAttach {
        // TODO: Your view has a parent, you can use it now.
        (view.parent as ViewGroup)?.yourAction()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have the view in OnHierarchyChangeListener, so I would suppose that you could add a callback to your views (by subclassing them with an interface) and call it from OnHierarchyChangeListener.  This way, your views will be called at the same time that the OnHierarchyChangeListener is called.

However, I won't be surprised that when this happens, that many properties of your views like their dimensions might not be defined yet.

Comment: Yes, of course: it's not an automatic process for the parents.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need that kind of control it may be best to make it a fragment. That way you get access to a much more granular lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this problem in a different angle, if you monitor the parents for attached views by implementing method onViewAdded.

Example:

```
public class LayoutInvokeChildAdded extends RelativeLayout {

    private OnDoneListener onDoneListener;

    public LayoutInvokeChildAdded(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LayoutInvokeChildAdded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LayoutInvokeChildAdded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAdded(View child) {
        super.onViewAdded(child);
        if (onDoneListener != null)
            onDoneListener.onDone(childe);
    }

    public void setOnDoneListener(OnDoneListener onDoneListener) {
        this.onDoneListener = onDoneListener;
    }
}
```