# Notification on View added to parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

When I build a `View` in Android dynamically I have to add it to a "parent" `ViewGroup` by calling

```
myLinearLayout.addView(myView);
```

I know that I can supervise the **`ViewGroup`** for any children to be added via the excellent [onHierarchyChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener.html), but in my case I need the feedback in the **`View`** itself. Therefore my question is:

**Is there something like a `View.onAddedToParent()` callback or a listener that I can build on?**

To make things very clear: I want the view to handle everything on its own, I am aware of the fact that I could catch the event in the "parent" and then notify the view about things, but this is **not** desired here. I can only alter the view

Edit: I just found [onAttachStateChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnAttachStateChangeListener.html) and it would seem to work for most situations, but I'm wondering if this is really the correct solution. I'm thinking a `View` might just as well be passed on from one `ViewGroup` to another without being detached from the window. So I would not receive an event even though I want to. Could you please elaborate on this if you have insight?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create custom view and do your stuff in its onAttachedToWindow

```
public class CustomView extends View {

   public CustomView(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
       super.onAttachedToWindow();
       Log.d("CustomView", "onAttachedToWindow called for " + getId());
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "added", 1000).show();
   }
}
```

If you want to ensure that your customview added to correct viewgroup which you want

```
@Override
 protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if(((View)getParent()).getId()== R.id.relativelayout2)
    {           
        Log.d("CustomView","onAttachedToWindow called for " + getId());
        Toast.makeText(context, "added", 1000).show();          
    }

}
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question I am a bit hesitant. Are you sure that this will also fire when the view is removed from a parent and added directly to another one? From the source it seems to me that there might be cases where this might not trigger appropriately (but I might be wrong of course)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Android source code, a view can't be moved to another layout unless `removeView()` is called first on its parent, and if you look at the code of `removeView()`, it calls `removeViewInternal()`, which in turn calls an overload of `removeViewInternal()`, which, on [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#5387) line calls `view.dispatchDetachedFromWindow()`, which, based on the Android source code on [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#18514) line calls `onDetachedFromWindow()`. Then the view gets added using `addView()`, which calls `onAttachedToWindow()` in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

In my opion you want like this;

CreateViews;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    layout.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new OnHierarchyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
            Log.e("View","removed");
            if(child instanceof CustomButton){
                CustomButton button = (CustomButton)child;
                button.addListener();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
            Log.e("View","added");
            if(child instanceof CustomButton){
                CustomButton button = (CustomButton)child;
                button.addListener();
            }
        }
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        CustomButton view = new CustomButton(this);
        view.setText("Button "+i);
        layout.addView(view, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layout.removeViewAt(layout.getChildCount()-1);
            }
        });

    }

    setContentView(layout);

}
```

Listener;

```
public interface OnAddedListener {

    public void addListener();

}
```

CustomButton class;

```
public class CustomButton extends Button implements OnAddedListener{

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener() {
        Log.e("","In button add listener");
    }



}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not what I want, I should have stressed this more in my question, I have therefore edited it now. The `View` is the only part of the application I want to modify, it has to take place **inside** it